# Standard logo dimensions and format?

Tags: logo, resize, scale

Are there any standards I should know about when designing a logo? I'm making a website for someone, I've gotta pretty kick-ass logo design going but I'm constantly redoing it when I have to resize it for different situations and I know this can't be right..

What are the dimensions for making a logo for the first time (using Photoshop)?

Do you make it over (re-write text for example) to cater different dimensions? I now know that merging and converting to a smart object gets rid of a lot of pixelation but it can still only be stretched so far before looking blurry.

Is importing into Illustrator and making a vector better?

This logo will be printed on clothing as well as being displayed in a range of sizes on pamphlets and the website.

Comment: Client: "Just make it bigger!"

Answer (score 4):

First, there is no **standards "dimension"** for designing a logo however you may think about logo **"Proportions"** which mean the ratio between the width and height. is it 1:1 , 1:6 , 1:2 or 3:4 ? ... etc. and when you render your logo to its final dimension you could scale it to any size you want.

So the question you have to ask to yourself: what proportion should my logo want to be? and the answer will be in the function of the activity that present your logo. is is a logo for cars company? or a logo for a school ... etc?

Second, when designing a logo, it is preferable to designing it using a vector graphic software, so you can change lines, colors, proportions and export it to any scale easily. also it will easy to render your logo in various color mode to suite web, T-shirts, stationary ...etc.

Comment: There's no real correlation between the ratio and the type of company.

Comment: In my opinion, sometimes we should think about the company activity to add either (stability or movement) to the logo and is it vertical or horizontal.

Comment: But isn't it a problem when I downscale my logo on a low-resolution screen, that it might not be pixel perfect? Because this is what always irritates me ... maybe I am thinking about pixel perfectness to much where it isn't really necessary ...

Answer (score 1):

> Hey is there any standards I should know about when designing a logo

No standards, but plenty of things to consider. For starters, where and how will the log be used? On business cards? Semi trucks? Billboards? TV ads? Faxes? Web sites? Etc, etc.

> What are the dimensions for making a logo for the first time in photoshop?

The dimensions are what you need them to be, but note that Photoshop isn't usually the ideal program to use. If possible, you want to be using a vector-based tool like Illustrator.

> Do you make it over (Re-write text for example) to cater different dimensions?

That's certainly an option.

Answer (score 1):

> Is importing into illustrator and making a vector better?

I'd suggest whenever possible to create your logo in Illustrator. Having the logo as a vector file will give you a great deal more flexibility when resizing a logo. If made as a vector, you can use the same file on a business card, and a billboard, due to the infinite scalability of vectors.

As for standard sizes, not really, but when creating a logo, if you must use Photoshop, your best bet would be to make the logo as large as possible, as you never know how the logo may need to be used in the future. With a pixel-based file, you can make it smaller, but enlarging it can be tough to get acceptable visual quality.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use 500x500 for a standard logo size on Illustrator. If its just shapes and letters you can freely  resize it without any pixelation.
Illustrator is what i recommend to use for such task such as logos, signs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend working with a square artboard (or close to it) for your logo, especially if it's for use on the web. I'm not saying to make your logo square, just a shape that will fit nicely *inside a square*. If you're going to want to use the logo on social media, you're going to need to crop it to a square anyway.